# LLVM C++ access and modify the content of a llvm::GlobalVariable

Tags: c++, llvm

I am new to LLVM I am trying to understand how to access the value of non-constant global variables (for constant I learned that it is possible through the initializer). At the moment I can access the global variables from their name with the following code:

```
const llvm::Module *m = ...;
std::string name = "name";
llvm::GlobalVariable *gv = m->getGlobalVariable(StringRef(name), true);
```

The types of these global variables are `i32` and `*i32`.

How can I access, print, and potentially change the actual integer value of these variables?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: what about the `LoadInst` and `StoreInst` instructions??

Answer (score 0):

The initializer sounds like the only value you can care about.

The global variable may have many values during its lifetime, but since your code uses `Module` and `GlobalVariable` I infer that your code runs at compile time, which is the exact start of the variable's lifetime. A variable's value at the start if its lifetime is the initializer.

You may of course reason about other values that are set; for that, you want to look at its [users()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html#a793bafeae1be7dfa4a7ad9661ed2c404), see which of those are [stores](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StoreInst.html) (or perhaps cmpxchgs). examine [their value operands](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StoreInst.html#a3250779697f5ea79833ac8f2ea1bc4c1) and reason about which value may be stored when. You can of course also change the store, to change the value being set.

Even more fun is to be had with cross-module access, AKA external globals; users() returns only in-module usage.

Comment: I actually want to monitor the values of those variables throughout the execution of the program. So periodically I want to check their current value and see if it has changed. I am doing this within KLEE which executes the LLVM bytecode of a target program. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see... you could also use users() to find all the stores and cmpxchgs that may change the variable, and add instrumentation next to them. That might work well for some source languages, but far from all. Klee is great, though.

Answer (score 0):

To track changes to a given global variable, `gv`, you could write an llvm pass that goes through all the `store` instructions in your bytecode.

When a `StoreInst` is seen, you check the second operand with `si->getOperand(1)->getName()` and see if it equals `gv->getName()`. If it does then you insert two `load` instructions for `gv` ; one just before `si`, and the other just after. See http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#creating-and-inserting-new-instructions

Now you have two `Value*` pointers to `gv`'s value before and after your original code put something in it. You can now insert an appropriate compare instruction corresponding to `gv`'s type to check if the values of these pointers  match.

The result of the comparison is an `i1` which tells whether or not `si` changed `gv`'s value.

You could then insert a call to `printf` and pass this result casted to int.